# Can we combine Future Continuous with Present Simple into grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: present-simple, future-continuous

While learning English grammar I noticed that we can combine **Past Perfect Continuous, Past Perfect** and **Past Continuous** tenses with following actions (also in past) described in **Past Simple**. 
e.g.: “**We were swimming** when it **started** to rain”
Similarly we can combine **Future Perfect Continuous** and **Future Perfect** with **Present Simple**. 
e.g.: "How long **will** John **have been working** at the company by the time he **retires**?"
Does this rule apply also to Future Continuous and we can create grammatically correct sentence with Future Continuous + Present Simple? If so, could you please give some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

*I will be watching TV when you get home.*